# Calling an object attribute within another object's method in python

Tags: python, function, oop, object, instance

i am making a MLP and connecting my final hidden layer to the output.

```
class connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.weight = 0
        self.network_output_index = 0
def connect(self,**network_instance**):
    **network_instance**.output_array[self.network_output_index] = self.value * self.weight

class network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.output_array = [0,0,0,0]
    blah blah python blah;
```

How do I call `network_instance`'s attribute `output_array`?

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing an indentation issue, this appears to work with no problem:

```
class connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.weight = 0
        self.network_output_index = 0

    def connect(self, network_instance):
        network_instance.output_array[self.network_output_index] = self.value * self.weight

class network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.output_array = [0,0,0,0]

c = connection()
c.value = 5
c.weight = 2

n = network()

c.connect(n)

print(n.output_array)

[10, 0, 0, 0]
```